# I want to update the same table twice in one query. What is the syntax for that?

Tags: mysql

I want to update 2 columns in the same table in one query, is that possible? This is what I want to do.

```
query = UPDATE "table_name" SET "column" = 0 WHERE "column" = 1
 AND 
UPDATE "table_name" SET "column" = 1 WHERE id = ID
```

When I look at it, it makes sense, but mysql doesn't seem to like the syntax.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update multiple **columns** of the same table in a single statement, but only if the **WHERE** condition is the same.

So this works:

```
UPDATE x SET foo = 'bar', oof = 100 WHERE y = 1
```

and it will set `foo` to `'bar'` and `oof` to `100` for every row where `y = 1` is true.

But your conditions do not match, so you will need two separate statements.

Comment: Looks like i'll have to do it in 2 statements. Thank you for you help.